# Pybind11/Nanobind: How to return class object and use methods from Python. How can I cast the C++ object to something whose methods I can use in Py

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, pybind11, nanobind

I'm not sure why I can't find any good discussion of this, I have been searching since yesterday.

How do you return a class object from C++ binding and use its methods in Python i.e.:

```
class A {
    ...
    void foo() {
        py::print("Hello world");
    }
}

class B {
    ...
    A bar() {
        a = A();
        // What do I return here if I want to return a and use it in Python
        // return a
    }
}
```

I want to then bind B and use it in Python

```
b_object = B()
a = b_object.bar()
a.foo()
```

How do I do this in Pybind, Nanobind or Boost Python (if the syntax for the latter is similar).

**I can't use lambdas when creating the `B` binding. The use case is actually more complex than what I've shown here.**

Comment: Which part of this is giving you problems? Exporting classes is commonplace in examples and you shouldn't have issues finding inspiration there.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Can I confirm that all I need to do is to add a binding for both classes in the `PYBIND_MODULE` and then I can just return the class as is? I couldn't find mention of this anywhere.